# Array search with multiple words

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like that:

```
(
(0) => Array
    (
        (uid) => '100',
        (name) => 'Blue t-shirt 4 years',
        (ean) => '123456'
    ),

(1) => Array
    (
        (uid) => '5465',
        (name) => 'blue shirt 24 years',
        (ean) => '123'
    ),

(2) => Array
    (
        (uid) => '40489',
        (name) => 'Shirt 4 Years',
        (ean) => '12345'
    )
);
```

I am trying to count how many entries in the array have all the words on the key name "shirt 4 years" case insensitive or have the same 'ean' number.

In that case would return 2. What's the best way to do that?

Comment: Share your try and expected output?

Comment: Is the data in a database?

Comment: @user2486 I was doing it as a query in the database. I was getting the data in the array, and after I was doing another query to count it. But it's making it too slow.

Comment: @user2182349 Yes, it is. But it's slow to retrieve this from the DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can prepare regex that matches provided words in any order:

```
function words_regex(array $words) {
    $regex = array_reduce($words, function($carry, $word) {
        return $carry . '(?=.*\b' .  preg_quote($word) . '\b)';
    }, '/');

    return $regex . '.*/i';
}
```

Having this function you can filter items and count them:

```
$regex = words_regex($words);

$count = count(array_filter($array, function($item) use ($regex) {
    return preg_match($regex, $item['name']);
}));
```

Here is [working demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c068fb08e4e4dcd418e8e0844f6fbdc09bb3addf).

Comment: How could I check if doesn't match the name, check if the EAN matches?

Answer (score 0):

Those are two different goals. The first one (count key name) is a simple `foreach` loop

1. Initialize your counter to 0
2. loop through the array and if test, increase counter

The second logic requires you to have an array of counter for each `ean`, loop through the array and count each `ean` into an array slot. Then you can loop through the array and find those that have count > 1

Combining the two through the same loop will work, but then you need to analyze the second condition.

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop through the array and check one by one if there are matched string and count it to a variable..

```
<?php
    $array = [
        ["uid"=>'100', 'name'=>'Blue t-shirt 4 years', 'ean'=>'123456'],
        ["uid"=>'5465', 'name'=>'blue shirt 24 years', 'ean'=>'123'],
        ["uid"=>'40489', 'name'=>'Shirt 4 Years', 'ean'=>'12345']
    ];
    echo("It's ".countArrayVal($array, 'name', 'shirt 4 years'));

    function countArrayVal($array, $key, $search){
        $count = 0;
        for ($i=0; $i < count($array); $i++) { //Loop
            if(stripos($array[$i][$key], $search)!==false) //Check matched string
                $count++; //Update the counter
        }
        return $count; //Return count
    }
```